# Enable loudspeaker programmatically during a voip call

Tags: ios, ios5, core-audio, voip, twilio

I want to enable loudspeaker programmatically during a voip call in ios app. Is it possible and how?

Comment: Swift 4 Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246539/enable-and-disable-speaker-in-xcode-ios-8-1-while-calling/50214838#50214838

Comment: Swift 4 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246539/enable-and-disable-speaker-in-xcode-ios-8-1-while-calling/50214838#50214838

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute key and the kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker property in Apple's Audio Session documentation.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.0**

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```