# Enable and disable speaker in Xcode ios 8.1 while calling

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, audio

I need to enable speaker while calling from app. I can successfully enable it but I am not able to disable it.

I am using this method:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setProximityMonitoringEnabled:NO];
NSLog(@"%d",enable);

UInt32 route;
route = enable ? kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker :
kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None;

AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                         sizeof(route), &route);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AudioSessionSetProperty is Deprecated.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/audiotoolbox/reference/audiosessionservicesreference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioSessionSetProperty

```
- (void)setAudioOutputSpeaker:(BOOL)enabled
{
    AVAudioSession *session =   [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *error;
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
    [session setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:&error];
    if (enabled) // Enable speaker
    {
        [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];
    }
    else // Disable speaker
    {
        [session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error];
    }
    [session setActive:YES error:&error];
}
```

Comment: hiii , Thanks for reply it enables speaker but it don't disable it then !
gives me error like : Master/sound  Underflow, buf_cnt=0, will generate 1 frame

Comment: It enables but cant able to disable !

Comment: it works for me. can you paste the full error log and please check whether something else is overriding your audio device

Comment: 16:52:27.501 strm0x1795f214  VAD re-enabled
16:52:37.709   Master/sound  Underflow, buf_cnt=0, will generate 1 frame
When i receive call and enable speaker with the code you gave and when try to disable , it shows this .

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 for Speaker Onn Off

```
//MARK:- Usage  for Enable
self.setAudioOutputSpeaker(enabled: true)

//MARK:- Usage  for Disable
self.setAudioOutputSpeaker(enabled: false)

//MARK:- Manual Speaker Enagle and Disable
func setAudioOutputSpeaker(enabled: Bool)
{
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    var _: Error?
    try? session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    try? session.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat)
    if enabled {
        try? session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
    } else {
        try? session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.none)
    }
    try? session.setActive(true)
}
```